# Is Yahweh the Golden Calf?

Tags: bible

Does the name  "Egeliah" found on ancient ostracon which translates to "bull calf of Yah" suggest that the Golden calves of Aaron and Jeroboam are actually symbols of Yahweh rather than deified animals? I have always thought that the Israelites worshiped the Golden Calf alone and that it was not an affiliated object to Yahweh. Lastly why is God portrayed as a bull in Numbers 24:8? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you're asking, with links or more explanations of the ostracon etc.

Comment: I have to agree that your question should be a little more specific as the topic is problematic. For example. The Egyptians (and other religions) did not worship the calf. They used it as tool to focus with by imagining the god in the space above the back of the calf. One has to assume that the Israelites did similarly. Maybe ask one thing and tell us what your source is.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is a common understanding of the passage.  On this interpretation the Israelites disobeyed the following commandment:

> “You shall not make for yourself a graven image, or any likeness of anything that is in heaven above, or that is in the earth beneath, or that is in the water under the earth; you shall not bow down to them or serve them; for I the Lord your God am a jealous God, visiting the iniquity of the fathers upon the children to the third and the fourth generation of those who hate me... (Exodus 20:4-5 RSV)

The following source lends credibility to this idea:

> Although both Exodus and Kings portray "calf worship" as disloyalty to YHWH, most scholars believe that it was not really an abandonment of Yahwism.  Archaeological finds, including the El texts from Ugarit, indicate that Near Eastern gods commonly were envisioned as standing invisibly on the backs of calves, bulls, or other powerful animals.  The calf figures were merely pedestals for the divine presence. (Harris and Platzner, *The Old Testament: An Introduction to the Hebrew Bible*)

See also Exodus 32:4, where the graven image is identified with the power that brought them out of Egypt, as well as verse 5 which includes a reiteration of their fidelity to the Lord.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: This is interesting.

Comment: Besides archeological evidence and the immediate contrast to the "no graven images" commandment (because humanity it's God's image, not a golden statue), it's also worth noting that there is a view that says the Israelites were supposed to ascend the mountain with Moses, but were too afraid of God's power, and only then did God restrict access to Moses himself. The calf, as such, is Israel further defining God in their own terms, which is an extension of defining good and evil on its own terms, which is the primary metaphor of taking from the tree of good and bad.

Answer (score 2):

If that is the suggestion of what you quote it is contrary to:

Exo 32:2 through 8 NKJV  And Aaron said to them, "Break off the golden earrings which are in the ears of your wives, your sons, and your daughters, and bring them to me." 3  So all the people broke off the golden earrings which were in their ears, and brought them to Aaron. 4  And he received the gold from their hand, and he fashioned it with an engraving tool, and made a molded calf. Then they said, "This is your god, O Israel, that brought you out of the land of Egypt!" 5  So when Aaron saw it, he built an altar before it. And Aaron made a proclamation and said, "Tomorrow is a feast to the LORD." 
6  Then they rose early on the next day, offered burnt offerings, and brought peace offerings; and the people sat down to eat and drink, and rose up to play. 
7  And the LORD said to Moses, ***"Go, get down! For your people whom you brought out of the land of Egypt have corrupted themselves. 8  They have turned aside quickly out of the way which I commanded them. They have made themselves a molded calf, and worshiped it and sacrificed to it, and said, 'This is your god, O Israel, that brought you out of the land of Egypt!' "***

There are two statements which debunk  the idea that the calf could be a representation of God.

1. ***"Go, get down! For your people whom you brought out of the land of Egypt have corrupted themselves.***

> God didn't even acknowledge that he brought them out of Egypt as it truly was Moses. If they were worshiping God why would he call it corruption?

2.***They have made themselves a molded calf, and worshiped it and sacrificed to it, and said, 'This is your god, O Israel, that brought you out of the land of Egypt!' "***

> God referred to it as 'god' which is indicative of a false God.

Also numbers 24:8 does not refer to God as a bull.

> Numbers 24:8  "God brings him out of Egypt; ***He has strength like a wild ox;*** He shall consume the nations, his enemies; He shall break their bones And pierce them with his arrows.

***He has strength like a wild ox;*** is along way from calling God a calf, and even more so a 'golden calf'.

Comment: lol. I was even too lazy to look up the Numbers verse. Good debunking.

Comment: There are at least two possible answers to this question: that the Israelites abandoned YHWH and worshiped the golden calf, or that they worshiped YHWH through the golden calf.  This answer makes an argument for the first position, but it does not present evidence ruling out the second position.  [Another](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/35961/is-yahweh-the-golden-calf/36001#36001) answer shows how the evidence can also be seen to support the second position.  It should be borne in mind that _positive evidence for the first position does not debunk the second position_.

Comment: @zippy2006 maybe you ought to reread my answer there is a lot of difference **in a god and the God**.

Comment: Like what?  What does the translation mean?  What does the Hebrew say?  How does it exclude the second position?  Thanks!

Comment: @BYE, the problem is that the Hebrew is ambiguous. Elohim can be either a true plural or an honorific one. The use of a lowercase 'g' is a necessary interpretive decision on the part of the translators, since it's only an english practice to use a capital for "the God". So, as a standalone verse it really can be "your gods," "your god," or "your God." The question then becomes, did those who saw the LORD appear as a pillar of fire believe that a different god rescued them from Egypt, or that the god who did rescue them, could be contained in a graven image.

Comment: Furthering the ambiguity is that Aaron announces a feast to YHWH after building the calf. So, he is either equating YHWH with the calf, or he is comfortable worshipping YHWH AND the calf. @zippy2006 rightly points out that the text is debatable, no argument completely debunking either position.